# how to check/uncheck checkbox in listview dynamically in android?

Tags: android

this is the code i am using to dynamically load data from database, but i am not getting how to check or uncheck checkbox dynamically? this is the code i am using.

```
String[] from = new String[]{"ToDisplay","MblNo", "_id"};

        // and an array of the fields we want to bind those fields to (in this case just tvViewRow)
        int[] to = new int[]{R.id.tvViewRow};


        // Now create a simple cursor adapter and set it to display
        SimpleCursorAdapter cursor = new SimpleCursorAdapter(this, R.layout.white_row, coloursCursor, from, to);

        setListAdapter(cursor);
        Cursor curs = DisplayWhiteAddress();
        curs.moveToFirst();
        int i=0;
        while(!curs.isAfterLast()){
            String s=""+curs.getString(2);

            myArrayList.add(i, s);
            s=""+curs.getString(0);

            myNumberList.add(i, s);
            ListIndices.add(i,Integer.parseInt(""+curs.getString(0)));

            curs.moveToNext();
            i++;
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the method:

```
cb.setChecked(true);
cb.setChecked(false);
```

to check/unchek a Check. If you can explain us where your CheckBox are...

Answer (score 0):

I don's see any checkbox in you code. But when at your code you know whether your checkbox should be checked or not, then use the "setSelected(Boolean)" method of the checkbox object to set it.

check here:  http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#setSelected%28boolean%29